# Android Fragments: Multiple Changes - App Crashes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a problem: I would like to replace one fragment with another one. So I wrote this code:

```
    FragmentTransaction mTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment statistics = new Statistics();
    Fragment home = new Home();
    mTransaction.add(R.id.container, home);
    mTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
    mTransaction.replace(R.id.container, statistics);
    mTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

The XML:

```
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that only one .commitAllowingStateLoss() call is fine, if I do it twice (as above) the app crashes. Unfortunately I need to call it multiple times. The same applies to .commit() . What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you adding a fragment then immediately replacing it with another?  Just an experiment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because after call .commit.., the transaction consider as closed.
So I think you just need to remove your first called .commit 
So the code will be

```
FragmentTransaction mTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment statistics = new Statistics();
Fragment home = new Home();
mTransaction.add(R.id.container, home);
mTransaction.replace(R.id.container, statistics);
mTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

If you still want to call .commit 2 times, just begin another transaction after first commit:

```
FragmentTransaction mTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment statistics = new Statistics();
Fragment home = new Home();
mTransaction.add(R.id.container, home);
mTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
mTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
mTransaction.replace(R.id.container, statistics);
mTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```